# Generate report with specific date

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm generate report using *iReport 4.7.0*

I want to generate the report by searching between 2 day,Example : from when to when.

And this is my code:

```
java.util.Date utilStartDate = date1.getDate();
java.sql.Date start = new java.sql.Date(utilStartDate.getTime());

java.util.Date utilStartDate2 = date2.getDate();
java.sql.Date end = new java.sql.Date(utilStartDate2.getTime());

try {
    JasperDesign jd = JRXmlLoader.load("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\Sales Report.jrxml");
    String sql = "Select * from Order1 Where Order_Date between "+start+" and "+end+"";

    JRDesignQuery newQuery = new JRDesignQuery();
    newQuery.setText(sql);
    jd.setQuery(newQuery);
    JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd);
    JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr,null,conn);
    JasperViewer.viewReport(jp,false);
} catch(Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.getMessage());
```

I have error say that the document have no pages.

This is my first time doing this because previously I just generate the report without specific something.

Any could help?

Comment: How does your .jrxml file look? That file controls the layout of the report

Comment: It may also be worthwile to look into and make sure that the date data type is actually Date and not string or something else.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need apostrophees around the dates. Otherwise the dbms might think it is a arithmetic operation instead of a date.

In other words you probably have this:

```
"Select * from Order1 Where Order_Date between 2005-06-25 and 2008-04-13"
```

and thus 2005 - 06 - 25 = 1974 and 2008 - 04 - 13 = 1991 results in:

```
"Select * from Order1 Where Order_Date between 1974 and 1991"
```

Instead what you want is this:

```
"Select * from Order1 Where Order_Date between '2005-06-25' and '2008-04-13'"
```